# How to declare a variadic template function as a friend?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, friend-function

How to declare a variadic template function as a friend?

For example as follows:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    friend ??? MakeA ??? ; // What should be placed here ???

    A(T)
    {}
};

template<class T, class... Args>
A<T> MakeA(Args&&... args)
{
    T t(std::forward<Args>(args));

    return A(t);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's quite straightforward. It's simply a template declaration with the added `friend` specifier:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    template<class T1, class... Args>
    friend A<T1> MakeA(Args&&... args);

    A(T) { }
};
```