# How to make std::make_unique a friend of my class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, unique-ptr, friend-function

I want to declare `std::make_unique` function as a friend of my class. The reason is that I want to declare my constructor `protected` and provide an alternative method of creating the object using `unique_ptr`. Here is a sample code:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    // Somehow I want to declare make_unique as a friend
    friend std::unique_ptr<A<T>> std::make_unique<A<T>>();


    static std::unique_ptr<A> CreateA(T x)
    {
        //return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(x)); // works
        return std::make_unique<A>(x);         // doesn't work
    }

protected:
    A(T x) { (void)x; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A<int>> a = A<int>::CreateA(5);
    (void)a;
    return 0;
}
```

Right now I get this error:

```
Start
In file included from prog.cc:1:
/usr/local/libcxx-head/include/c++/v1/memory:3152:32: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'A<int>'
return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
                           ^
prog.cc:13:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::make_unique<A<int>, int &>' requested here
    return std::make_unique<A>(x);     // doesn't work
                ^
prog.cc:22:41: note: in instantiation of member function 'A<int>::CreateA' requested here
std::unique_ptr<A<int>> a = A<int>::CreateA(5);
                                    ^
prog.cc:17:5: note: declared protected here
A(T x) { (void)x; }
^
1 error generated.
1
Finish
```

What is the correct way to declare `std::make_unique` as a friend of my class?

Comment: try compiling with clang - it complains: `main.cpp:17:39: error: friends can only be classes or functions -     friend `std::unique_ptr<A<T>> std::make_unique<A<T>>();` with the error location being the template instantiation.

Comment: Interestingly, compiler with -std=c++14 and this one disappears, and the errors point towards @Praetorian's answer below.

Comment: @marko The above error is with clang. I am on MSVC (vs 2013) now though. Doesn't work there either.

Comment: Ok. my bad - different standards versions.  Besides this trick being hard to pull off, I question this as a contract design - it seems you are conflating rather that separating concerns here.

Comment: Well the main problem is I don't know who to trust. For example, based on Praetorian's answer, it works on clang but not on msvc :P

Comment: I would agree with the advice given that it is implementation dependant and that you can't rely on it working.  Probably time for a redesign :/

Comment: You're also pushing your luck if you expect MSVC to be complaint with C++14 - even in the most recent versions. They seem to have more or less got C+11 nailed these days.

Comment: @marko The irony is that a couple of weeks ago I was arguing with a friend about msvc. I kept telling him stuff like "aaaw come on, msvc is fine, you'll see". I am pretty sure I owe him a beer now! :P

Comment: @marko Regarding your first comment, `make_unique` was added in C++14, so if you're using `-std=c++11` the compiler has no idea what `make_unique` you're referring to in the friend declaration.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) perfect forwards the arguments you pass to it; in your example you're passing an lvalue (`x`) to the function, so it'll deduce the argument type as `int&`. Your `friend` function declaration needs to be

```
friend std::unique_ptr<A> std::make_unique<A>(T&);
```

Similarly, if you were to `move(x)` within `CreateA`, the `friend` declaration would need to be

```
friend std::unique_ptr<A> std::make_unique<A>(T&&);
```

This will get the code to [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fadd42d8e928a63e), but is in no way a guarantee that it'll compile on another implementation because for all you know, `make_unique` forwards its arguments to another internal helper function that actually instantiates your class, in which case the helper would need to be a `friend`.

Comment: Indeed that works! But what if I want to pass more arguments to my constructor? If my constructor is for example `A(const std::string& str1, const std::shared_ptr& ptr1)` which is more complex than an integer.

Comment: @TheCrafter I think you'll have to befriend the corresponding `make_unique` signature, I don't think you get more generic because partial specialization of function templates is not allowed. My suggestion is to forget about `make_unique` and have `CreateA` return `unique_ptr<A>(new A(...))`. Unlike `make_shared`, `make_unique` doesn't buy you very many advantages.

Comment: Ok I got it. I just wanted to know if there is a workaround!! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Is a varadic template friend not allowed?

Comment: @paulm Yes, in general that's [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793151/241631). But in this case, if you write `template<typename... Args> friend std::unique_ptr<A> std::make_unique<A>(Args&&...);`, that's partial specialization of a function template, which is not allowed.

Comment: I tried the same sort of thing with `shared_ptr` in gcc and, as Praetorian warned might happen, it doesn't work because `make_shared` doesn't call the constructor itself, but uses a helper function to do so. I think, rather than rely on unguaranteed implementation details, I should give up the slight efficiency gain of `make_shared` and use `std::shared_ptr(new MyClass(...))` instead.

Comment: What happens if the protected constructor's parameter is `A*`? The above doesn't seem to work...