# using make_unique and make_shared statically doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to learn the kinds of factory patterns I can use in C++. I'm not sure why I can't return a unique ptr. I can return a shared ptr just fine. Here's my code:

```
class FactoryMethodExample {
    FactoryMethodExample() {}
public:
    static FactoryMethodExample get_instance() {
            return {};
    }

    static FactoryMethodExample * get_pointer() {
        return new FactoryMethodExample;
    }

    static unique_ptr<FactoryMethodExample> get_unique_instance() {
        return make_unique<FactoryMethodExample>();
    }

    static shared_ptr<FactoryMethodExample> get_shared_instance() {
        return shared_ptr<FactoryMethodExample>();
    }

    void verify() {
        cout << "I exist" << endl;
    }
};
```

This code doesn't compile. I get this error :

```
error: calling a private constructor of class 'FactoryMethodExample'
return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
```

Comment: `make_unique` cannot use a private constructor: it's not a friend of the class. You'd have to do the old-fashioned `return std::unique_ptr<FactoryMethodExample>(new FactoryMethodExample());`

Comment: Also note that your `get_shared_instance()` doesn't actually return an instance - it returns a null shared pointer.

Comment: use `return std::make_shared<FactoryMethodExample>()` (after making the constructor accessible) if you have `std::make_shared()` available, otherwise use `return shared_ptr<FactoryMethodExample>(new FactoryMethodExample);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, your old-fashioned way worked. However I was not able to make it work via the friend class method. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: Don't do that; it's non-portable. Even if you manage to befriend `std::make_unique`, it could legally delegate the actual work to some internal helper function (which wouldn't be a friend, leaving you right where you started). So your program would compile with some standard library implementations but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` examples are not comparable.

**`make_unique`** creates a `unique_ptr` initialised with a value.

**`shared_ptr`** is just a constructor call of the `shared_ptr` class, which will leave it initialised with a null pointer.

This is why you are getting two different results.

The reason you have an error, is because you have a private constructor. The easiest solution is to make make_unique (and make_shared) friends.

See the following question for a bit of guidance: [How to make std::make_unique a friend of my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905030/how-to-make-stdmake-unique-a-friend-of-my-class)

In addition, your function names may be misleading. **get_shared_instance** implies that the same instance will be returned every time, where I think you want to return a shared_ptr of a new instance?

Comment: I was not able to make this work with the friend class. Do I just add `friend std::unique_ptr<FactoryMethodExample> std::make_unique<FactoryMethodExample>();` ?