# make_unique doesn't compile for creating a singleton instance

Tags: c++, singleton, c++14, unique-ptr, private-constructor

All,

I am using C++14 and am making a more-or-less standard Singleton. I am using the latest Visual Studio 2017.  This code works:

```
#include <memory>
class A
{
public:
  static A& getInstance()
  {
    if (instance == nullptr)
      instance = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A());
    return *instance;
  }

private:
  A() {}
  static std::unique_ptr<A> instance;
};
std::unique_ptr<A> A::instance = nullptr;
```

However, when I change the creation of the singleton instance to this:

```
instance = std::make_unique<A>();
```

I get a compilation error that I am trying to access a private member:

```
Error   C2248   'A::A': cannot access private member declared in class 'A'      
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory   2510
```

This feels like a bug to me, as the two forms should be identical in function? Thoughts?

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33905030/241631. `make_unique` is a function just like any other, why should it be able to call private members of your class?

Comment: In any case, you can avoid all this by defining the function as `static A& getInstance() { static A instance; return instance; }`

Comment: @Praetorian Except that leaves a possibility of a Static DE-initialization Order Fiasco.

Comment: @aschepler How? I don't see any additional limitations compared to the OP's version.

Comment: Both solutions suffer from race conditions and from the problem of reentrancy. That said, singletons are usually considered a bad idea, so I'd avoid that anyway.

Comment: @Praetorian in this particular case the static initialization would be fine; but in my specific case it is a large and complex object; and the static initialization order might be problematic; I have learned that dynamic allocations in this sort of instance can resolve a whole lot of headaches.  Although make_unique() is a function I would have expected the two forms of initialization to be synonymous.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What is the race condition in Praetorian's solution?  The Meyers Singleton is thread-safe as of C++11, and the OP has indicated they are using C++14.

Comment: Ulrich in this case the code will be single-threaded; protecting this for thread-safety is straightforward. I disagree with singletons being bad ideas as a general principle; but they need to be used judiciously.

Comment: @DGehlhaar As Nevin said, what I posted is already thread safe post C++11. And I still don't see a static initialization order problem that dynamic allocation will solve compared to a function local static (which is only initialized the first time you call `getInstance`)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<A>(new A())` calls your private constructor, then passes that new object to the constructor of unique_ptr.  `std::make_unique<A>()` calls an external function that then attempts to invoke your object's constructor, which is private, so it fails

Comment: @Praetorian in general if you have a type that depends on another static type (let's say that "A" makes reference to "B" which contains a static variable) you can get into all kinds of trouble regarding which is initialized in what order; it can get messy; I have spent a lot of time dealing with this sort of issue. And it is compiler-dependent. I try to use dynamic allocation for this sort of thing if possible.

Comment: Using the approach with a pointer from multiple threads seems to be obviously a race condition, just because two threads could simultaneously write the shared pointer object. I'd take Nevin's word that the non-pointer approach works as of C++ 11. Further, if creation of the singleton instance indirectly involved access to that instance (circular dependency) that would probably end bad. Usually infinite recursion, but that depends on the code in between. For the non-pointer variant, it could involve use of a partially constructed object instead.

Comment: @DGehlhaar: "need to be used judiciously" -- that's true. I'd prefer a compile-time error. For that I use dependency injection, which also makes code easier to test in isolation.

Comment: @DGehlhaar But it seems to me that dynamic allocation won't protect you from static initialization order if your dynamic object relies on static objects that have not been initialized.

Comment: I recommend this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729 and put **all** your static objects inside functions that return their references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of `std::unique_ptr<>` is to control the lifetime of the object pointed to. You may pass a `std::unique_ptr<>` around, but that will also transfer ownership of the object pointed to. This concept does not match very well with the concept of a singleton. There is only one place that is ever allowed to create (or delete) the singleton. You don't really need a `std::unique_ptr<>`for that. As already said in the comments, there are simpler ways for that. I would prefer @Praetorian's suggestion:

```
static A& getInstance() 
{
     static A instance;
     return instance;
}
```

The reason why you can't use `std::make_unique<>()` to instantiate your class is that the constructor is private. To access it, you need the accessing function to be a `friend`. Have a look at [How to make std::make_unique a friend of my class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33905030) for that. Another solution is to provide a public constructor requiring a private type as argument, as described int [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996628/2311167).

Comment: Where is it specified that you should make `make_unique` a friend?

Comment: The constructor for `class A` is private. `std::make_unique<>()` needs to access that constructor. That's why OP gets a compile error. So, _if_ OP still wants to use  `std::make_unique<>()` for the singleton (which I and many commenters above would not recommend), then making `std::make_unique<>`  a friend of the class to instantiate would solve the problem.

Comment: "_std::make_unique<>() needs to access_" Yes **I do see it**. Is that **documented**? Where is **guaranteed** to be the case? You know, some sort of "contract".

Comment: @curiousguy ISO/IEC 14482 2014 ch. 20.8.1.4 [unique.ptr.create]: _Returns_: `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`.  Obviously, to create an object of type `T`, you need to have access to the constructor. You may also want to have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: Does it say anything about friend?

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that `make_unique` doesn't use a helper function, so making it a `friend` isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Nevin This has already been worked out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905304).

Answer (score 4):

```
instance = std::make_unique<A>();
```

this creates the `A` within the function `make_unique`.  But the ctor you want to call is private.

```
private:
  struct ctor_permission_t{
    explicit ctor_permission_t(int){};
  };
public:
  explicit A(ctor_permission_t):A(){}
};
```

then

```
instance = std::make_unique<A>(ctor_permission_t{0});
```

The `ctor_permission_t` acts as a token giving its possessor the right to construct an `A`.  We pass this to `make_unique`.

The `explicit int` ctor in `ctor_permission_t` makes it impossible to create it without naming the type, and only within instances and friends of `A` can name it because it is private.  This makes it difficult to bypass this permission token.

Comment: This is a very cool solution. However, the ctor of `ctor_permission_t` needs an argument. So, you need to write `instance = std::make_unique<A>(ctor_permission_t{0});`. There is also a typo in the ctor of `A` ('_t' missing). IMHO the solution works because `ctor_permission_t` is private, not because of the `explicit int`. If works very well with `struct ctor_permission_t{}`. Then you can call `instance = std::make_unique<A>(ctor_permission_t());` and it is still impossible to instantiate `A` without having access to the private type `ctor_permission_t`.

Comment: @adr `{}` can construct it without the int arg.  So someone could just `A({})` if the explicit int ctor was missing, without naming the ctor permission type.

Comment: Disagree. If I remove the explicit ctor of `ctor_permission_t` I still can't call `A({})` because the entire `struct ctor_permission_t` is private and I can't access it from outside. Tested it (with gcc 6.3) and I get _error: ‘struct A::ctor_permission_t’ is private within this context_ as expected.

Comment: @adrian [live example](https://godbolt.org/g/bfmiJA).  Also compiles in latest clang.  Either your compiler has a bug or your example differs.  Because `struct A{ private: struct B{}; public: A(B){}};` allows non friends to `A a({});` under the standard.  If you want to know more, use the [ask question] link and post a new SO question about this; comments are a poor place for Q&A on language details.

Comment: Your example is missing a private default ctor for `A` to be comparable to OP's situation. If you add `private: A() = default;` to your example, it won't compile anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the others answers' and fix some flaws in them:
You can make a private structure with a private constructor which is a friend with your class. Then make your class constructor public but with an additional argument of that private structure.

Also its better to use static function witch return a reference instead of the bare static variable.

```cpp
#include <memory>

class A
{
  struct Private
  { 
    friend A;
    private:
      explicit Private() = default; 
  };

public:
  static A * getInstance()
  {
    if (!instance())
      instance() = std::make_unique<A>(Private());

    return instance();
  }

  A(Private) {};

private:
  static std::unique_ptr<A> & instance()
  {
    static std::unique_ptr<A> inst;
    return inst;
  }
};
```

Or if you really dont need any special configurations which requires using a pointer and heap allocation (like initializing the instance in a special thread or ...) :

```cpp
class A
{
public:
  static A & getInstance()
  {
    static A instance;
    return instance;
  }

private:
  A() = default;
};
```