# Correct way to implement singleton with shared pointer?

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm attempting my first bigger C++ object and I'm running into a bit of a problem when it comes to implementing a singleton using a shared pointer.

When I try to compile the following, I Visual Studio gives me this error:

> "Error    C2248   'PaletteManager::PaletteManager': cannot access private
> member declared in class 'PaletteManager' {omitted}\xmemory   line 228"

I'm guessing the issue is because I have a private constructor/destructor and make_shared is trying to call the constructor. This access problem makes sense to me, but if I want to use a shared pointer as the way to access my singleton object, what am I supposed to do? The code works just fine with a raw pointer, but I wanted to try and do things the clean way with a smart pointer.

Here is the header file for the code in question:

```
class PaletteManager
{
private:

    // array representing palette colors
    uint* paletteColors;

    // private constructor/destructor because singleton
    PaletteManager();
    ~PaletteManager();

    // load palette from file TODO: not implemented
    void loadPallette();

    static std::shared_ptr<PaletteManager> instance;

public:

    const uint PALETTE_MAX_COLORS = 4;

    uint getPaletteColor(uint idx);

    // singleton accessor
    static std::shared_ptr<PaletteManager> getInstance();
};
```

And here is the function at issue in the cpp file:

```
std::shared_ptr<PaletteManager> PaletteManager::instance = nullptr;

std::shared_ptr<PaletteManager> PaletteManager::getInstance()
{
    if (!PaletteManager::instance) 
    {
        PaletteManager::instance = std::make_shared<PaletteManager>();
    }

    return PaletteManager::instance;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/40337728#40337728

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PaletteManager::instance = std::make_shared<PaletteManager>();
```

This results in `std::make_shared` attempting to `new` a `PalletteManager` object, and then construct a `std::shared_ptr` from it. This is what `std::make_shared` does, that's how it works.

This is not going to work here: that's because `PalletteManager` has a private constructor, and `std::make_shared`, the template in the C++ library, is not it's `friend`.

You will have to explicitly `new` the object in `getInstance`, a member of this class, which can use the private constructor, and then manually construct the `std::shared_ptr` from the pointer to this new object.

TLDR: you cannot use `std::make_shared` for an object with a private constructor. C++'s rules do not allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `std::make_unique<>()` a friend function of your class with the private constructor.  Presumably this would work with `std::make_shared<>()` too? (But I haven't tested it.)

For example, see:
[How to make std::make_unique a friend of my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905030/how-to-make-stdmake-unique-a-friend-of-my-class)