# How to allow a std::unique_ptr to access a class's private destructor or implement a C++ factory class with a private destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, smart-pointers, friend-class

I'm quite far into the development of a game using SDL, OpenGL and C++ and am looking for ways to optimize the way the game switches between GLSL shaders for lots of different objects of different types. This is much more of a C++ question than an OpenGL question. However, I still want to provide as much context as I can, as I feel some justification is needed as to why the proposed Shader class I need, needs to be created / deleted the way that it is.

The first four sections are my justifications, journey & attempts leading up to this point, however my question can likely be answered by just the final section alone and I've intentionally written it as a bit of a tldr.

### The necessity for a Shader class:

I've seen many implementations online of OpenGL shaders being created, compiled and deleted all in the same function when game objects are created during gameplay. This has proven to be inefficient and far too slow in particular sections of my game. Thus, I've required a system that creates and compiles shaders during a load-time and then intermittently uses/swaps between them during game-time before being deleted later.

This has lead to the creation of a class(`Shader`) that manages OpenGL shaders. Each instance of the class should manage one unique OpenGL shader each and contains some complex behavior around the shader type, where it's loaded in from, where it's used, the uniform variables it takes, etc.

With this said, the most important role of this class is to store the `GLuint` variable `id` that is returned from `glCreateShader()`, and manage all OpenGL calls that relate to the OpenGL shader with this `id`. I understand that this is effectively futile given the global nature of OpenGL(as anywhere in the program could technically call `glDeleteShader()` with the matching `id` and break the class), however for the purposes of intentionally encapsulating all OpenGL calls to very specific areas throughout the entire codebase this system will *drastically* reduce code-complexity.

### Where the problems start...

The most "automatic" way to manage this `GLuint id`, would be to invoke `glCreateShader()` on the object's construction and `glDeleteShader()` on the object's destruction. This guarantees(within OpenGL limits) that the OpenGL shader will exist for the entire lifetime of the C++ Shader object and eliminates the need to call some `void createShader()` and `deleteShader()` functions.

This is all well and good, however problems soon arise when considering what happens if this object is copied. What if a copy of this object is destructed? That means that `glDeleteShader()` will be called and effectively break all copies of the shader object.

What about simple mistakes like accidentally invoking `std::vector::push_back()` in a vector of Shaders? Various `std::vector` methods can invoke the constructor / copy constructor / destructor of their type, which can result in the same problem as above.

Okay then... how about we do create some `void createShader()` and `deleteShader()` methods even if it's messy? Unfortunately this just defers the above problem, as once again *any* calls that modify the OpenGL shader will desynchronize / outright break all copies of a shader class with the same `id`. I've limited the OpenGL calls to `glCreateShader()` and `glDeleteShader()` in this example to keep things simple, however I should note that there are many other OpenGL calls in the class that would make creating various instance/static variables that keep track of instance copies far too complicated to justify doing it this way.

The last point I want to make before jumping into the class design below is that for a project as large as a raw C++, OpenGL and SDL Game, I'd prefer if any potential OpenGL mistakes I make generate compiler errors versus graphical issues that are harder to track down. This can be reflected in the class design below.

### The first version of the `Shader` class:

It is for the above reasons that I have elected to:

- Make the constructor `private`.
- Provide a public `static create` function that returns a pointer to a new Shader object in place of a constructor.
- Make the copy constructor `private`.
- Make the `operator=` `private` (Although this might not be necessary).
- Make the destructor private.
- Put calls to `glCreateShader()` in the constructor and `glDeleteShader()` in the destructor, to have OpenGL shaders exist for the lifetime of this object.
- As the `create` function invokes the `new` keyword(and returns the pointer to it), the place with the outside call to `Shader::create()` must then invoke `delete` manually (more on this in a second).

To my understanding, the first two bullet points utilize a factory pattern and will generate a compiler error should a non-pointer type of the class be attempted to be created. The third, fourth and fifth bullet points then prevent the object from being copied. The seventh bullet point then ensures that the OpenGL Shader will exist for the same lifetime of the C++ Shader object.

### Smart Pointers and the main problem:

The only thing I'm not a huge fan of in the above, is the `new`/`delete` calls. They also make the `glDeleteShader()` calls in the destructor of the object feel inappropriate given the encapsulation that the class is trying to achieve. Given this, I opted to:

- change the `create` function to return a `std::unique_ptr` of the `Shader` type instead of a `Shader` pointer.

The `create` function then looked like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Shader> Shader::create() {
    return std::make_unique<Shader>();
}
```

But then a new problem arose... `std::make_unique` unfortunately requires that the *constructor* is `public`, which interferes with the necessities described in the previous section. Fortunately, I found a solution by changing it to:

```
std::unique_ptr<Shader> Shader::create() {
    return std::unique_ptr<Shader>(new Shader());
}
```

But... now `std::unique_ptr` requires that the *destructor* is public! This is... better but unfortunately, this means that the destructor can be manually called outside of the class, which in turn means the `glDeleteShader()` function can be called from outside the class.

```
Shader* p = Shader::create();
p->~Shader(); // Even though it would be hard to do this intentionally, I don't want to be able to do this.
delete p;
```

### The final class:

For the sake of simplicity, I have removed the majority of instance variables, function/constructor arguments & other attributes but here's what the final proposed class (mostly)looks like:

```
class GLSLShader {

public:
    ~GLSLShader() { // OpenGL delete calls for id }; // want to make this private.

    static std::unique_ptr<GLSLShader> create() { return std::unique_ptr<GLSLShader>(new GLSLShader()); };

private:
    GLSLShader() { // OpenGL create calls for id };

    GLSLShader(const GLSLShader& glslShader);
    GLSLShader& operator=(const GLSLShader&);

    GLuint id;

};
```

I'm happy with everything in this class, aside from the fact that the destructor is public. I've put this design to the test and the performance increase is very noticeable. Even though I can't imagine I'd ever accidentally manually call the destructor on a `Shader` object, I don't like that it is publicly exposed. I also feel that I might accidentally miss something, like the `std::vector::push_back` consideration in the second section.

I've found two potential solutions to this problem. I'd like some advice on these or other solutions.

1. Make `std::unique_ptr` or `std::make_unique` a `friend` of the `Shader` class. I've been reading threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905030/how-to-make-stdmake-unique-a-friend-of-my-class), however this is to make the constructor accessible, rather than the destructor. I also don't quite understand the downsides / extra considerations needed with making `std::unique_ptr` or `std::make_unique` a `friend` (The top answer to that thread + comments)?
2. Not use smart pointers at all. Is there perhaps a way to have my `static create()` function return a raw pointer(using the `new` keyword), that is automatically deleted inside the class / when the `Shader` goes out of scope and the destructor is called?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I didn't read all your question, but I think enough to get the idea. Seems to me all you really need is a factory method that returns `std::shared_ptr`s? Wouldn't that solve all your problems?

Comment: Also, the idea of trying to "protect users" from manually calling the destructor is dubious to say the least. If they want to break your class they will always be able to. No one will ever accidentally make a manual call to a destructor.

Comment: Protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli. This exercise overthinks a design about something that is (with almost absolute certainty) not going to be an issue.

Comment: "Manually call a destructor"?  Who does that?  If someone is that malicious or clueless they can just edit your header file and remove the `private:`.  Or add a friend.  Or do whatever the heck they want.  @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica said it fine: "Protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli."  Anyway, who's going to be _programming_ against this interface anyway?  _You're_ not going to make the mistake of manually calling the destructor ...

Comment: Thankyou for your response. My line of thinking originally went down this route due to the vector issue I came across in the second section of my post. If I didn't construct my Shader objects in the way that I have and had a `vector<Shader>`, invoking the `push_back()` function on this vector would invoke the destructors and break the objects. My thinking was that perhaps there was some other thing I'm not thinking of that could automatically invoke the destructor like the vector.push_back(), hence I thought it was safest to find a way to make it private. What are your thoughts on this @super?

Comment: Your `GLSLShader` class is neither copyable nor movable. It's impossible to create instances of it in a vector. How is `push_back` going to be a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, love the quote from before btw. I understand that `push_back` isn't going to be a problem. I mentioned this in relation to why I changed the class design after the second section of my post, which is why I said "If I didn't construct my Shader objects in the way that I have". My concern was not about vectors/push_back, but that there was some other concept that I hadn't considered since updating the design. Maybe something else in the STL that would still be able to call the destructor when I don't want it to, etc.

Comment: Instead of relying on `std::unique_ptr`, you might implement move constructor/assignment for `GLSLShader` (possibly using `std::optional<GLuint>` to know for "invalid" id).

Comment: @Jaymaican I understand your thinking. But the fact that you have a smart-pointer to manage the lifetime of the object removes all such worries. A smart-pointer will never copy the underlying object (unless done explicitly by the user, and that would also be impossible here since you have private copy ctor and assignement). If the factory method is the only way to create instances you have your bases covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a context challenge.

## You are solving the wrong problem.

> `GLuint id`, would be to invoke `glCreateShader()` on the object's construction and `glDeleteShader()`

Fix the problem here.

The **Rule of Zero** is that you make your resource wrappers manage lifetimes, and you don't do it in business logic types.  We can write a wrapper around a `GLuint` that knows how to clean itself up and is move-only, preventing double destruction, by hijacking `std::unique_ptr` to store an integer instead of a pointer.

Here we go:

```
// "pointers" in unique ptrs must be comparable to nullptr.
// So, let us make an integer qualify:
template<class Int>
struct nullable{
  Int val=0;
  nullable()=default;
  nullable(Int v):val(v){}
  friend bool operator==(std::nullptr_t, nullable const& self){return !static_cast<bool>(self);}
  friend bool operator!=(std::nullptr_t, nullable const& self){return static_cast<bool>(self);}
  friend bool operator==(nullable const& self, std::nullptr_t){return !static_cast<bool>(self);}
  friend bool operator!=(nullable const& self, std::nullptr_t){return static_cast<bool>(self);}
  operator Int()const{return val;}
};

// This both statelessly stores the deleter, and
// tells the unique ptr to use a nullable<Int> instead of an Int*:
template<class Int, void(*deleter)(Int)>
struct IntDeleter{
  using pointer=nullable<Int>;
  void operator()(pointer p)const{
    deleter(p);
  }
};

// Unique ptr's core functionality is cleanup on destruction
// You can change what it uses for a pointer. 
template<class Int, void(*deleter)(Int)>
using IntResource=std::unique_ptr<Int, IntDeleter<Int,deleter>>;

// Here we statelessly remember how to destroy this particular
// kind of GLuint, and make it an RAII type with move support:
using GLShaderResource=IntResource<GLuint,glDeleteShader>;
```

now that type knows it is a shader and cleans itself up it non-null.

```
GLShaderResource id(glCreateShader());
SomeGLFunction(id.get());
```

apologies for any typos.

Stuff that in your class, and copy ctors are blocked, move ctors do the right thing, dtors clean up automatically, etc.

```
struct GLSLShader {
  // public!
  ~GLSLShader() = default;
  GLSLShader() { // OpenGL create calls for id };
private: // does this really need to be private?
  GLShaderResource id;
};
```

so much simpler.

```
std::vector<GLSLShader> v;
```

and that just works. Our `GLShaderResource` is semi-regular (move only regular type, no sort support), and `vector` is happy with those.  Rule of 0 means that `GLSLShader`, which owns it, is also semi-regular and supports RAII -- resource allocation is initialization -- which in turn means it cleans up after itself properly when stored in `std` containers.

A type being "Regular" means it "behaves like an `int`" -- like the prototypical value type.  C++'s standard library, and much of C++, likes it when you are using regular or semi-regular types.

Note that this is basically zero overhead; `sizeof(GLShaderResource)` is the same as `GLuint` and nothing goes on the heap.  We have a pile of compile-time type machinery wrapping a simple 32 bit integers; that compile-time type machinery generates **code**, but doesn't make the data more complex than 32 bits.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/joz1sK).

The overhead includes:

1. Some calling conventions make passing a `struct` wrapping only an `int` be passed differently than an `int`.
2. On destruction, we check every one of these to see if it is `0` to decide if we want to call `glDeleteShader`; compilers can sometimes prove that something is guaranteed zero and skip that check.  But it won't tell you if it did manage to pull that off.  (OTOH, humans are notoriously bad at proving that they kept track of all resources, so a few runtime checks aren't the worst thing).
3. If you are doing a completely unoptimized build, there are going to be a few extra instructions when you call a OpenGL function.  But after any non-zero level of `inline`ing by the compiler they will disappear.
4. The type isn't "trivial" (a term in the C++ standard) in a few ways (copyable, destroyable, constructible), which makes doing things like `memset` illegal under the C++ standard; you can't treat it like raw memory in a few low level ways.

---

## A problem!

Many OpenGL implementations have pointers for `glDeleteShader`/`glCreateShader` etc, and the above relies on them being actual functions not pointers or macros or whatever.

There are two easy workarounds.  The first is to add a `&` to the `deleter` arguments above (two spots).  This has the problem that it only works when they are actually pointers now, and not when they are actual functions.

Making code that works in both cases is a bit tricky, but I think almost every GL implementation uses function pointers, so you should be good unless you want to make a "library quality" implementation.  In that case, you can write some helper types that create constexpr function pointers that call the function pointer (or not) by name.

---

Finally, apparently some destructors require extra parameters.  Here is a sketch.

```
using GLuint=std::uint32_t;

GLuint glCreateShaderImpl() { return 7; }
auto glCreateShader = glCreateShaderImpl;
void glDeleteShaderImpl(GLuint x) { std::cout << x << " deleted\n"; }
auto glDeleteShader = glDeleteShaderImpl;

std::pair<GLuint, GLuint> glCreateTextureWrapper() { return {7,1024}; }

void glDeleteTextureImpl(GLuint x, GLuint size) { std::cout << x << " deleted size [" << size << "]\n"; }
auto glDeleteTexture = glDeleteTextureImpl;

template<class Int>
struct nullable{
  Int val=0;
  nullable()=default;
  nullable(Int v):val(v){}
  nullable(std::nullptr_t){}
  friend bool operator==(std::nullptr_t, nullable const& self){return !static_cast<bool>(self);}
  friend bool operator!=(std::nullptr_t, nullable const& self){return static_cast<bool>(self);}
  friend bool operator==(nullable const& self, std::nullptr_t){return !static_cast<bool>(self);}
  friend bool operator!=(nullable const& self, std::nullptr_t){return static_cast<bool>(self);}
  operator Int()const{return val;}
};

template<class Int, auto& deleter>
struct IntDeleter;

template<class Int, class...Args, void(*&deleter)(Int, Args...)>
struct IntDeleter<Int, deleter>:
  std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>
{
  using base = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>;
  using base::base;
  using pointer=nullable<Int>;
  void operator()(pointer p)const{
    std::apply([&p](std::decay_t<Args> const&...args)->void{
        deleter(p, args...);
    }, static_cast<base const&>(*this));
  }
};

template<class Int, void(*&deleter)(Int)>
using IntResource=std::unique_ptr<Int, IntDeleter<Int,deleter>>;

using GLShaderResource=IntResource<GLuint,glDeleteShader>;

using GLTextureResource=std::unique_ptr<GLuint,IntDeleter<GLuint, glDeleteTexture>>;

int main() {
    auto res = GLShaderResource(glCreateShader());
    std::cout << res.get() << "\n";
    auto tex = std::make_from_tuple<GLTextureResource>(glCreateTextureWrapper());
    std::cout << tex.get() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for this brilliant answer. I wish I could change the name of my post so that a greater number of future users seeking overall assistance with for their GLSL Shaders/Program classes are more likely to see this. I just have a couple of quick follow-up questions. Would you mind briefly explaining the role of the `friend` keyword in the nullable `struct`? Was also wondering what the role the `const` keyword serves in `operator Int()const{return val;}` and what would happen if it wasn't there? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, just on one quick additional note. I've tried to implement this and have gotten a compile error... `error C2975: 'deleter': invalid template argument for 'IntResource', expected compile-time constant expression`. I should note I'm using GLEW v2.1. In "glew.h", there is `#define glDeleteShader GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewDeleteShader)`. It gives the error: `argument of type "PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC" is incompatible with template parameter of type "void (*)(GLuint)"`. Would the best way to fix this be a wrapper for glDeleteShader? `void glDeleteShaderWrapper(GLuint id) { glDeleteShader(id); }`?

Comment: @Jaymaican So here `glDeleteShader` is a non-`constexpr` function pointer.  But a pointer to that function pointer is going to be `contexpr`.  So ... add another level of indirection to `void(*deleter)(Int)`.  As simple as `void(*&deleter)(Int)` worked in a test case (do it everywhere `deleter` is used in the above code, not just one spot, or you'll get conversion errors elsewhere).  Alternatively, you can wrap it in a lambda.

Comment: Hi and thanks again - I have a follow-up question that I'm sure future users may come across. There are calls in OpenGL such as glGenVertexArrays() which take two arguments(a size and an id). You would want to keep track of both the size and the id for proper deletion later. Following on from your above implementation, how might you support an equivalent to `GLShaderResource=IntResource<GLuint,glDeleteShader>;` that instead of a `GLuint` type, uses a `struct` containing a `GLuint` and a `GLsizei` with an appropriate deleter that takes more than one argument?

Comment: @Jaymaican make a `std::tuple<some_nullable_type, Ts...>` resource wrapper that takes the tuple and calls the deleter with `std::apply`?  Or maybe a bit less generic; it would depend on how often you use the size.  If the size is only used (or almost only used) at destruction, shove it into the deleter and make it not-stateless.

Comment: Thanks again. The size would almost exclusively used in the destruction. Could you elaborate a bit further on how to shove it into the deleter and make it not-stateless? I'm struggling to understand how & where I would be shoving/inputting the value into the deleter aswell as where this value is stored (size). (Does this involve modification of the IntDeleter struct?)

Comment: @Jaymaican see above.  I made the deleter inherit from a (possibly empty) tuple, then pass those tuple arguments to the deleter function.  When you construct the unique ptr, the first is the pointer (int) the second argument is sent to the tuple.  I wrote a wrapper that creates a texture (supposedly with openGL APIs), then returns a tuple of the int and the size; we then use make from tuple to make the unique ptr, passing the size the the deleter.  See the cppreference page on unique ptr consturctor with a deleter for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a **deleter** yourself, and let the deleter be a friend of your class.
Then edit your declaration like this:

```
static std::unique_ptr<GLSLShader, your_deleter> create();
```

Comment: I would say that **evil** people who would do `p->~Shader()` can still do `your_deleter{}(p)` or similar.

Comment: Thankyou @aleck099 this is the type of solution that I was originally looking for and pretty much solves the issue I mentioned in the post. Just a note to any future readers, the others have also raised some good points in the comments of the original post about why this isn't a big issue in the first place.

Comment: In fact nobody would call a dtor directly, so it is actually no need to make any dtors private.